# LongListSelector doesn't refresh correctly when only 1 object is in collection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro, longlistselector

I have a problem with caliburn micro and Longlistselector.

BindableCollection from my viewmodel is bind to ItemSource in LLS in view.

In OnActivate method I load data from local database to my BindableCollection to refresh LLS. From my list page I can go to another page to edit selected item on list, and after save I return back to my list page. 
Then again OnActivate method is invoked which  fetch all objects of SomeType from local database and assign new BindableCollection so LLS is updated.

This works great when more than 1 element is in local database. But when there is only one object on local database, the LLS is not updated after edit, still presents the same data before edit.

What is more, when I go again to edit this object to edit page, the correct data are displayed.

Below are my OnActivate method

```
protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();

        Task<List<Person>>.Factory.StartNew(() => _service.GetPresons()).ContinueWith(
            x => Execute.BeginOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                this.Persons = new BindableCollection<Person>(x.Result);
            }));
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try not recreating the collection on every page activation.

Put this collection init to your constructor

```
Persons = new BindableCollection<Person>()
```

and in change the OnActivate method to

```
protected override void OnActivate()
{
    base.OnActivate();

    var res = _service.GetPresons();
    Persons.Clear();
    Persons.AddRange(res);
}
```

Comment: Already tested, doesn't work. I think this could be problem with LongListSelector which in some circumstance could cache items